# More specific path than $DOMDocument->getNodePath();

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodes, domdocument

I currently need a an XPath path to an element. The path must contain an attribute that uniquely identifies each element along the path (In this case, the name attribute).

`$DOMDocument->getNodePath();` returns the path, but no attributes. The attributes are neccessary as the XML will be changing quite a bit.

I am currently writing a method to manually go through and check each element in the path for the name attribute, then inserting it into the string at the appropriate point. Is there an easier/faster/not as hackish way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xsh solution from @choroba can be translated to PHP source using `DOMXpath::evaluate()`:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//address') as $address) {
  $path = '';  
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('ancestor-or-self::*', $address) as $ancestor) {
    $path .= '/'.$ancestor->nodeName;
    if ($name = $ancestor->getAttribute('name')) {
      $path .= '[@name = "'.$name.'"]';
    }
  }
  var_dump($path);
}
```

`ancestor-or-self::*` is an Xpath expression that fetches all element nodes starting from the context node up to the document element.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use XPath to get the string. For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
for //address {
    for ancestor-or-self::*
        echo :s :n '/'
                   name()
                   xsh:if(@name, concat('[@name="', @name, '"]'),'') ;
    echo ;
}
```

Runnnin it on the following XML

```
<root>
  <customers name="2014">
    <customer name="John">
      <address/>
    </customer>
    <customer name="Jane">
      <address/>
    </customer>
    </customers>
    <customers name="2015">
      <customer name="Daniel">
        <address/>
      </customer>
      <customer name="Dave">
        <address/>
      </customer>
    </customers>
</root>
```

I'm getting

```xml
/root/customers[@name="2014"]/customer[@name="John"]/address
/root/customers[@name="2014"]/customer[@name="Jane"]/address
/root/customers[@name="2015"]/customer[@name="Daniel"]/address
/root/customers[@name="2015"]/customer[@name="Dave"]/address
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put php in tags. I am now looking up xsh though to see if it would help. Thanks.